# Retrieving the maximum value from an Integer column in an Access table

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, data-retrieval

I have a textfield in a NetBeans frameform. I added a "Generate" button, and when I click it the program should find the largest value from the column "book_code" in a table named "books" and should display "generated value+1" in the textfield.

I use a class method to connect to my database so you won't find any code for connecting the database.

I have tried some coding but I am not able to generate the maximum value from book_code column of table books. Here is what I did:

```
String b_code="select max(Book_code) from books";
try
{
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(b_code);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();

    int a=rs.getInt(b_code);
    System.out.println("Book code is "+a);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , e);
}
```

The maximum value in book_code column is 103, and when I click the "generate" button I would like to see 104 in the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two (2) issues with your code:

1. You create your ResultSet but you don't call `rs.next()` before you try to retrieve the value.
2. When you do try to retrieve the value you use the variable that contains the SQL string, and there is no column in the ResultSet that matches

This should work better:

```java
String b_code="select max(Book_code) from books";
try {
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(b_code);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    int a = rs.getInt(1);
    System.out.println(String.format("max(Book_code) is %d", a));
} catch(Exception e) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , e);
}
```

Comment: yeah thats working fine but showing the max value and i want maxValue+1.....i will that on my own now....thnx for the support.

Comment: Sir can you help me put the value of a into jTextField1   ..
I tried 
jTextField1.setText(a);
instead of 
System.out.println(String.format("max(Book_code) is %d", a));

its showing me an error "Integer cannot be converted to string" .